# Deleting Future Events only in Google Calendar Event Series

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I have an event Series in my calendar, and I can not delete Future Events only using Apps Script. The only function I found is "deleteEventSeries" which deletes all the events (previous and past).

I tried looping on Calendar events within a certain period, and delete events that has the same Event Series ID as my target Event Series, But this took too much time to be executed.

Is this something that can be accomplished using Google Apps Script ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "deleting" future events, change the recurrence rule to include recurrence ending date by using [until(date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#untilenddate)

AFAIK for existing recurrente events / series events first we have to get the actual recurrence rule and replace it with a new rule including the end date, the last by using [setRecurrence(recurrence, startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event-series#setRecurrence(EventRecurrence,Date,Date))

Related

- [Change exisiting calendar event series date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30724417/1595451)
- [Getting Recurrence of API Google Calendar Events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30703963/1595451)
- [How to Read Calendar Event Recurrence Settings Using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770235/1595451)