# Change exisiting calendar event series date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I have a problem regarding the changing of dates of a [Google Calendar Event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) series. The API doesn't have any methods for changing the dates.

Is there a way I can do this? I am creating a form where when you edit the due date of the request in the spreadsheet, it will also edit the calendar event series.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is incorrect it is possible to change or update the date of a Google calendar event using the Google Calendar API.

**Option nr 1:**

You can patch the event in the body you include the variables you would like to update or patch.  In this case date.

> [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) Updates an event.

**Request**

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId}/events/{eventID}?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2008-09-26T12:01:00+02:00"
 }
}
```

**Response**

200 OK

**Option nr 2**

Another option would be to first use [Events.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) to get the event change what you need then do [events.update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update). This will do an update on everything in the event. While Patch just changes one what you need.